# Looping a mysql query leads to error 'localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500'

Tags: php, mysql

I have to add 37 columns to my table, namely X_1,X_2...X_37.

So, I figured instead of manually doing it, why not use a simple PHP script?

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","physics101","Ionic");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

for($i=3;$i<37;$i++)
{
  $field = 'X_'.$i;
  $query ="ALTER TABLE `Participants` ADD $field TINYINT(1) NOT NULL 
  DEFAULT '0' " ;
  $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
  if($result) 
            echo 'Query successfull. <br>' ;
  else 
            echo 'Query failed. <br>'

}
?>
```

This gives a `localhost can't handle request` error page.

Although , when I ran individual queries to add `X_1` and `X_2`, it worked!

Comment: Once you hit the `else` statement, you will probably error, seeing as the last echo in your code is missing it's `;`.

Comment: You should also use prepared statements vs injecting a variable right into the query string.

Comment: A `500` is a server related error, generally meaning a code issue. Most times, it will produce useful log messages, probably in apache's log files.

Comment: I feel dumb AF. The missing semi colon wins again. :(

Comment: Adding 37 fields like this feels like you might be headed down a bad design path. Consider normalizing that design or if this is intended to be a 1 or 0 value in these columns, use either the bit data type or consider using code to build 5 bytes to contain your flags (5 bytes x 8 bits per byte = 40 bits / flags). Either way, you might want to ask for a more thorough review of your approach.

Comment: @jhilgeman Yeah I abandoned that approach . Learnt about foreign keys and normalization and now I just had to add 2 fields instead of 74. Knowledge is power !